# How to use JOptionPane to display info

Tags: java, joptionpane

I need some help writing a program

Using this code I am able to enter in a track name, artist, etc.

I have a problem that I cannot now show this information in JOptionPane to display all of my info

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class TestTrack
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Track name");
      String name = myScan.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Artist");
      String Artist = myScan.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Track length seconds");
      String seconds = myScan.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Album");
      String Album = myScan.nextLine();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Trackinfo:")
   }   

}
```

So I guess I would want the pop out window to say

Track Name: "blank"

Artist: blank

Another question I have is how to ask this question multiple times by using "while" and asking if I would like to add another track

Sorry if I am using any terminology incorrectly I just started to learn Java

Comment: You have quite the mix of console and window commands. "System.out.printl" prints to a command prompt like window where a JOptionPane wouild be like a message box. Check out some JOptionPane turtorials here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Answer (score 1):

This line: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,**"Trackinfo:"**)
Contains what the pop-up window will contain. You pass in what you want its contents to be as the 2nd parameter, which is currently "Trackinfo".

To incorporate a while loop, you'll have to have a loop control variable, or a condition that will break the loop. In my example I used a string. My example uses a while loop that will continue as long as the string is not equal to "quit".

```
String test = "";
while( ! test.equals("quit") ) {
//use Scanner to get the next value the user enters
//ask for track info
//display that info in a message box
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To obtain this:

[image]

Note: the texts of the OK and Cancel buttons are localized, if your computer is set to US locale you doesn't see 'Annuler"... ;-)

code this:

```
int answer = 0;
do {

   /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Here you put the code which set the variables name, artist, seconds... (1)
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

   final String title   = "Track info";
   final String message =
      "<html><table>" +
      "<tr><td>Track name"      + "</td><td>" + name    + "</td></tr>" +
      "<tr><td>Artist"          + "</td><td>" + artist  + "</td></tr>" +
      "<tr><td>Track length seconds</td><td>" + seconds + "</td></tr>" +
      "<tr><td>Album"           + "</td><td>" + album   + "</td></tr>" +
      "</table>";
   answer =
      JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
         null, message, title, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION );
} while( answer == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION );
```

(1) You may choose [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) or GUI whith [JOptionPane.showInputDialog()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 0):

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Trackinfo:" + "\nArtist: " + Artist + "\nseconds: " + seconds + "\nAlbum: " + Album)
```

Each '\n' means a new line. for doing this multiple times, you should place your code in a while loop, something like this:

```
while(!(Artist == "end")) {
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `myScan.next()` instead of `myScan.nextLine()`

To output the information into the Message Dialog, use

```
String trackInfo = "Track Name: " + name + " | Artist : " +artist+ " | Track Length: " + seconds + " | Album: " + album;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, trackInfo, "Trackinfo", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```